# Female doctor- no handshake, but ok with medical touch during examination

Tags: practical-islam, muslim-practices, touching

I (obviously male body, though I actually identify as genderqueer) recently visited my doctor for the first time. She declined to shake hands during intros "for religious reasons", and even dodged around my instinctively outstretched hand so as not to accidentally touch it. During the examination itself though, she repeatedly touched the bare skin all over my body during the skin cancer screening, while examining various moles and such.

She's educated at one of the best medical schools in the world, and is a highly effective doctor.

I would like to be polite to her by understanding her preferences a bit better, and not putting her in a position where she needs to tell a patient "no, for religious reasons". I'm not asking for whether her behavior is "correct" or not. I'm merely trying to understand the likely motivations behind her behavior, and how I might be able to avoid putting her in a potentially uncomfortable position in the future. If it matters, I live in California.

Comment: The general rule of thumb in an Islamic society is that female doctors treating women and male doctors treating the men. Incase, it is difficult to find a doctor of the same gender, then it is permissible to seek treatment from the opposite gender. Islam places the value of life above other worldly things. Hence, even pork or alcohol become temporarily permissible in case of a life threatening situation.

Comment: From your question, I'd assume she doesn't like to shake a man's hand as you are non-mehram to her. Islam doesn't allow Muslims of either gender to touch each other unless they are Mehram or there is an emergency.This is out of respect and to avoid fitna. W.r.t touching you during the procedure, this becomes part of the ruling where she has to first treat a patient irrespective of the gender if there is no male doctor available. Also since you are in USA, she is trying her best to balance between her religion and her constitutional duties as a citizen and doctor.